# TraceSource defined in App.config not used c#

Tags: c#, logging, trace, tracesource

My goal is to log errors and information in my C# command line application to log files. To not reinvent the wheel I used some examples to activate `TraceSource` in my project using the `App.config` file.

This is my `App.config` file, which should create two log files, one for errors and one for level information. The console listener is not required, it's only included for testing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="BrokerTrace"
                    switchValue="All">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="Console"
                         type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"
                         traceOutputOptions="DateTime">
                        <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"
                                initializeData="Error"/>
                    </add>
                    <add name="FileError"
                         type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                         traceOutputOptions="DateTime"
                         initializeData="BrokerError.log">
                        <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"
                                initializeData="Error"/>
                    </add>
                    <add name="FileInfo"
                         type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                         traceOutputOptions="DateTime"
                         initializeData="BrokerInfo.log" >
                        <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"
                                initializeData="Info"/>
                    </add>
                    <remove name="Default" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Inside the C# code of the project I create the instance of the `TraceSource` and log events:

```
private static TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("BrokerTrace");

private static async Task Main()
{
    ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "Start application");
    ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1, "Start application");
    ts.Flush();
    ts.Close();
}
```

My expectation is that after the application run there are two files `BrokerError.log` and `BrokerInformation.log` created with one entry each. But no log file is created.

What I also tried, is to check the listeners of the `TraceSource` object. By adding this lines of code at the beginning of the `Main` method:

```
foreach(var listener in ts.Listeners) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("TraceSource listener: " + listener.ToString());
}
```

The result is `TraceSource listener:  System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener`. So I think the `app.config` file is not correctly loaded and a default `TraceSource` object is created instead of my definition in the `app.config`.

What is wrong with my `app.config` file or with the usage of the `TraceSource`?